# RecylerView: Choosing View Holders

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a doubt on ViewHolders in Recycler View, Which is a better approach

i) Using a single ViewHolder with all the View items of diffrent type views and identify them using if/else or switch case: 
like:

```
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   LinearLayout ll1;
   LinearLayout ll2;
   ...
   ...
   LinearLayout lln;
   TextView tv1;
   TextView tv2;
   ...
   ...
   TextView tvn;

  switch(viewType)
  {
   case 1: ...
          break;


   case 2: ...
          break;

   case 3:...
          break;
   case n:...
          break;

  }

}

where n > =100;
```

OR

ii) Use n different ViewHolders

```
public class CustomViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

 ...
 }

 public class CustomViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

 ...
 }

  ...

 public class CustomViewHoldern extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 ..

. 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Android sample code ( http://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/src/com.example.android.recyclerview/CustomAdapter.html ), the example indicates that the former method should be used.

For most conceivable cases, one ViewHolder would be enough for one RecyclerView to hold all views.  You probably shouldn't create more than one ViewHolder unless you really needed to for some specific reason.

Comment: The posted example doesn't show any approach for different viewTypes.  I'm curious about the reasoning for why you should not have different view holders for different type of views.

Comment: The posted example allows for different viewTypes in the parameter to the onCreateViewHolder method.  An approach to it is given by by the original person posting the question above.  I didn't say you shouldn't have different view holders for different views, I said if there was a specific reason to do so you should.  But there's no reason to do so if it's unneeded.  If Google thought each different view should always have its own holder, they wouldn't have included a viewType parameter in the example onCreateViewHolder method.  In other words, DRY over WET.